# How to build coffee script files without generating js files?

Tags: coffeescript, textmate, sublimetext2

In textmate, I can build the coffee script files (command + B) and it will generate the JS files on the flight without creating new files in the same directory. When I tried to build (command + B) in sublime text 2, it somehow generates JS files in the same directory. How to avoid this so that it behaves the same way like textmate?

Comment: What build system are you using in ST2?

Comment: yes, I'm using ST2 for both windows and mac

Comment: @Ream don't think he's asking what OS you're using, he's asking what system you use to perform the build

Answer (score 1):

Sublime text 2 does allow you to do this as well. Go to Package Manager and download CoffeeCompile https://github.com/surjikal/sublime-coffee-compile.

Once you have installed this package you would typically right click on an open .coffee file and select "Coffee Compile". However Mac OSX Mountain Lion seems to have issues using your path variable to find the coffee command and may throw an error along the lines of: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

If you get this problem do the following:
1. Go to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/CoffeeCompile/coffee_compile.py
2. Go to line 34 under 'quiet': True,
3. Add the following line: 'path' : '/usr/local/bin'

Restart Sublime Text 2 and try Coffee Compile again and it should work.

Comment: I am the author of this plugin and I approve this message. By the way, there is now a configuration option to set the path.

Comment: I tried to install the mentioned package through package manager in sublime, then I built. What I get is "Error: Cakefile not found in..." ; it sounds like Cakefile is nowhere to be found. I checked some wiki on coffeescript page [Link](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/[HowTo]-Compiling-and-Setting-Up-Build-Tools), but I don't know how to continue from that.